# How to install Nvidia driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

First of all after installation of Ubuntu 14.04 I was having problem - system freezes after few minutes of work.

I installed `nvidia-current` driver, it helped. I decided to install something more newer(I want to use GPU calculation with CUDA, finally).

I tried "additional drivers" 331. Didn't worked. Black screen after rebooting. I tried to install Nvidia drivers from offical site(last one, 346).

Also black screen or blank. Tried Xorg drivers - recommended 349 and 346. Same...Black screen.

I have GTX 590. I completely new to Linux, so getting lost in it. Why is it happening, whom drivers I should use and how to get it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem and I solved it like this (Actually [Raphael](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/119706/raphael) solved) like this:

- First find out which Graphic Card you are using (Exact model)

  You can contact the manufacturer or `lspci` and search for **3D controller** .
- Go to [Official Nvidia website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) and  Manually find drivers for your NVIDIA products
- And Select appropriate version of Linux (64bit or 32bit)
- <kbd>Search</kbd>
- Now know your driver number (ex : Version:   352.63 )(No need to download the *.run file just know the version)
- Switch to your default driver in **Additional Drivers**:

  [image]
- Now in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) run this command to remove all previous installations of Nvidia Drivers:

  `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`  <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Add this repository : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352` **REPLACE 352 WITH YOUR LATEST DRIVER VERSION from Nvidia**(don't worry about the decimals 352.xx => 352)
- Reboot after the installation is complete.

This worked well for me : I am using Nvidia GeForce 820M.

Answer (score 1):

Open Software & Updates app in Ubuntu and it allows to install NVIDIA driver from GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Download Nvidia driver from http://www.geforce.com/drivers

To install the driver from source:

**Disable nouveau**

1. open any tty other than GUI by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f[1-6]</kbd>
2. stop lightdm/gdm or whatever is your display manager

   `sudo stop lightdm`
3. run the script

   `sudo sh NVIDIA----.sh`

**solving problems**

4. if something goes wrong close the installer and reboot then try again
5. still same problem the nvidia installer will make a black list in **/etc/modprobe.d/**
6. if this is not generated you have to make such file to black list nouveau
7. Run sudoedit `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` and fill it with this:

   `blacklist nouveau`
8. If the problem is not solve you have to add the string "**nomodeset**" to your `/etc/default/grub`, in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= line`
9. then update the grub

   `sudo update-grub`