# Whats the best way to install drivers?

Tags: drivers

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, been using it for about a week (I love it). Can someone tell me what the best way to install video drivers is? I've been having some troubles. I have a GeForce 750ti and am on 14.04. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer of mine might help you http://askubuntu.com/a/723809/441517

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for new users to install video drivers is by using the Software & Updates tool.

Press `Super` (the windows key) to open dash, type "additional drivers" into the text box to see a list of available drivers. It should look something like this:

[image: List of available drivers]

Once you've found the driver and clicked on it, just press the apply changes button and enter your password. You will probably need to restart before the new driver takes effect.

If you don't see the driver you want listed then you may need to allow more software sources. Click on the Ubuntu Software tab and check the 4 checkboxes like this:

[image: Ubuntu Software]