# Ubuntu works without nvidia but stuck at login screen with nvidia

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, login

I have Nvidia graphics card installed and the Ubuntu used to work without any issue till yesterday. Unfortunately, it is now stuck at the login screen. I switched to terminal mode (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and removed Nvidia drivers using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

It works! However, I want to use Nvidia drivers so after logging in successfully, I installed Nvidia drives from "additional drivers" under "software and updates" in Ubuntu. After rebooting, it again stuck at login screen.

Below is the permission info. for `.Xauthority` file:

```
ravi@lab:~$ ls -la .X*
-rw------- 1 ravi ravi 48 Feb 20 11:43 .Xauthority
-rw------- 1 ravi ravi 48 Feb 20 11:27 .Xauthority.bak
```

I am not able to figure out the cause of the problem. Below is the content of `dmesg`:

```
[    1.342426] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    1.544607] Adding 16734204k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16734204k SSFS
[    1.594473] systemd-udevd[359]: starting version 204
[    1.596107] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 3600.032 MHz
[    1.620273] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    1.631667] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    1.649728] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    1.651556] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    1.681165] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    1.690956] type=1400 audit(1550630628.420:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=487 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    1.690962] type=1400 audit(1550630628.420:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=487 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    1.690965] type=1400 audit(1550630628.420:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=487 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    1.691995] type=1400 audit(1550630628.420:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=493 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    1.691999] type=1400 audit(1550630628.420:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=493 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    1.692002] type=1400 audit(1550630628.420:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=493 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    1.693989] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: irq 182 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.768260] checking generic (d1000000 7f0000) vs hw (c0000000 10000000)
[    1.768261] checking generic (d1000000 7f0000) vs hw (d0000000 2000000)
[    1.768262] fb: conflicting fb hw usage nouveaufb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
[    1.768280] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    1.768906] nouveau E[  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] unknown chipset, 0x134000a1
[    1.768910] nouveau E[     DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22
[    1.769175] nouveau: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -22
[    2.019597] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    2.229627] init: failsafe main process (750) killed by TERM signal
[    2.415213] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[    2.415250] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    2.415251] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.415255] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.415257] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.415259] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.418438] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    2.418447] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    2.418451] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    2.425587] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    2.425608] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    2.425634] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    2.446701] type=1400 audit(1550630629.176:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=837 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    2.446704] type=1400 audit(1550630629.176:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=837 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    2.465787] init: cups main process (842) killed by HUP signal
[    2.465817] init: cups main process ended, respawning
[    2.497078] type=1400 audit(1550630629.224:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=916 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    2.558491] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    2.588489] init: alsa-restore main process (1031) terminated with status 19
[    2.598291] Switched to clocksource tsc
```

Below is the content of `sudo lshw -c video`

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for ravi: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
```

*PS: I know the similar type of questions is asked many times but I am not able to figure out the cause of this problem. I guess that some Nvidia configuration files need to be cleaned properly.*

Comment: Looks like your drivers for nvidia are wrongly installed.
Can you post the output of `sudo lshw -c video`? (Also, refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612077/how-to-install-nvidia-driver) link for installing driver properly)

Comment: Thank you very much. The output of `sudo lshw -c video` is added to the question. Nvidia driver was installed from "additional drivers" under "software and updates". Please let me know if you need more info. I am online!

Comment: Please note that the output of `sudo lshw -c video` is taken after removing nvidia driver, because I cannot run `sudo lshw -c video` if the driver is installed, since the login stuck!

Comment: I'm also using Ubuntu 14.04, and encountered the same problem, with the same "solution" (`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`). I've created a topic at: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413017.

Comment: @user3409662: yeah! I guess we both stuck at the same problem. Unfortunately, I am not able to identity the exact cause. Removing the Nvidia driver is not a permanent solution.

Comment: @user3409662: Are you able to fix the issue? If so, can you please help me?

Comment: No, I'm still using the "Nouveau" driver currently.

Comment: @user3409662: I am going to try upgrading NVIDIA drivers using PPA tomorrow and let you know if it works!

Comment: @user3409662: I upgraded and installed `nvidia-410` from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y` but the problem persists. I don't want to reinstall the OS this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also was affected by this bug/effect. As workaround I also switched to the Nouveau driver first. As in the linked topic at ubuntuforums (from user3409662) was mentioned already, several packages have been updated last week, also shim-signed. Interestingly this package seems not to be necessary for me, because I disabled SecureBoot for my system (Ubuntu 14.04, Geforce GTX 750 Ti) by using mokutil some years ago (necessary to use VirtualBox again).

So I decided to uninstall shimsigned (used Synaptic for this), rebooted and saw no negative effects. In the terminal I installed my previously used Nvidia driver again:
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-410`. No errors appeared and after rebooting the graphical login was working again, Nvidia driver loaded. Tested some games (native and Wine based ones) – everything worked.

Comment: Thanks, klicker for the suggestion. Before I proceed, let me confirm from you that you want me to remove `shim-signed` package but not `shim`? Also, you want me to disable the secure boot? I will apply your suggestions after your confirmation. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ravi Joshi You are welcome. On my system `shim` and also `systemd-shim` are still installed. Probably not necessary anymore because I deactivated SecureBoot as mentioned above. But I didn't want to change to many packages at once and the effect appeared after `shim-signed` has been updated.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will remove `shim-signed` using synaptic and then will install NVIDIA using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-410`. Give me a few days as I am out of the city!

Comment: It worked for me (`sudo apt-get remove shim-signed`, then `sudo apt-get install nvidia-384`, and then reboot).

Comment: klicker, you are God!!! Thank you so much for the suggestion. It worked well! Can you quickly describe, how did you find out the culprit?

Comment: @Ravi Joshi, the first hints were given in [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413017) - @user3409662 (many thanks to him for giving the essential hints) mentioned  here that he opened this topic. I opened then the Software Center of Ubuntu and checked which updates have been installed last Friday on my PC and indeed `dkms` and `shim-signed` have been updated. And since the Nvidia driver is not loaded something must prevent it - therefore `shim-signed` seemed to be the suspect. But what I also don't understand: If SecureBoot is off, why suddenly `shim-signed` interferes?

Comment: _what I also don't understand: If SecureBoot is off, why suddenly shim-signed interferes_ Exactly! Secure boot is disabled in my computer from the BIOS settings. Strange to see this bug!!! Thanks again for the help!